# Sqlite inserting values in table not properly working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Am new to using sqlite in swift.I'm using sqlite to add Todo list for create, insert, select and update the table.Three values am using title, description and date.

create table code

```
 //the database file
    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("TodayNote.sqlite")


    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }

    if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Todos (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, desc TEXT, date TEXT)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
    }
```

insert values

```
//the insert query
        let queryString = "INSERT INTO Todos (title, desc, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
        //creating a statement
        var stmt: OpaquePointer?
        //preparing the query
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, title, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, desc, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, date, -1, nil)
            if sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE {
              print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
              print("Could not insert row.")
            }
        } else {
            print("INSERT statement could not be prepared")
        }
```

and show the values

```
//this is our select query
    let queryString = "SELECT * FROM Todos"

    //statement pointer
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?

    //preparing the query
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        //traversing through all the records
        while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            let id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
            let title = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
            let desc = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))
            let date = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))
            //adding values to list
            todoList.append(TodoList(id: Int(id), title: title, desc: desc, date: date))
            tableViewHeroes.reloadData()
        }
    } else {
        print("Select query not working properly")
    }
```

But the date value is show in all the field. I don't get what am missing in this code.
Can anyone solve this issues.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any error log when you are trying to insert something?

Comment: No Am getting successful message only

Comment: Have you checked the entries in your local DB file? is it appearing there?

Comment: can you please tell me how to check that entries

Comment: It might be in your document directory.
Have you created a DB file first or it is going to generate runtime?

Comment: I've created DB in programmatically. but i don't know where to get that file.

Comment: I'm really new for sqlite in swift.

Comment: your ```fileURL``` is the path where your actual DB file will take place. you can go there using finder's Go > Go to Folder

Comment: But am using iPhone not simulator. For iPhone where it'll be

Comment: In Xcode > Window > Devices & Simulators > Your Device > Your App > Show Content (or something else *don't know the exact name of option*)

Comment: yes i got DB file while run in simulator. same value stored in DB also like title = 06 , desc = 06/12/2, date = 06/12/2019

Comment: Okay so the issue is fetching the data from the DB, isn't it?

Comment: I've inserted like tilte = hi, desc = hey hey and date = 06/12/2019. but in DB values is different which i did n't enter in textField

Comment: Can u make sure that u insert the correct values, it seems that u insert the wrong values

Comment: if i added title textfield value more than 10 character and description textview more than 20 character means it's inserted perfectly. i don't get why it's inserting like that if less than 10 character